# Should a TFRecord contain multiple observations or one?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tfrecord

I see in [explanation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#read_the_tfrecord_file) a TFRecord contains multiple classes and multiple images (a cat and a bridge). When it was written, both images are written into one TFRecord. During the read back, it is verified that this TFRecord contains two images.

Elsewhere I have seen people generating one TFRecord per image, I know you can load multiple TFRecord files like this:

`train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("<Path>/*.tfrecord")`

But which way is recommended? should I build one tfrecord per image, or one tfrecord for multiple images? If put multiple images into one tfrecord, then how many is maximum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, it is possible to save an arbitrary amount of entries in a single `TFRecord` file, and one can create as many `TFRecord` files as desired.

I would recommend using practical considerations to decide how to proceed:

- On one hand, try to use fewer `TFRecord` files for easier handling moving files in the filesystem
- On the other hand, avoid growing `TFRecord` files to a size that can become a problem for filesystem
- Keep in mind that it is useful to keep separate `TFRecord` files for train / validation / test split
- Sometimes the nature of the dataset makes it obvious how to split into separate files (for example, I have a video dataset where I use one `TFRecord` file per participant session)

Comment: Thank you @prouast this reminds me of how HDFS storing data as multi parts.